# Polars message: eval_binary_same_type!(left_aexpr, +, right_aexpr) = None

Tags: python, python-polars

I have encountered a message as in the title when running some simple polars code. Example code and its outputs are provided below:

```
import datetime
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [datetime.date(2022, 12, 1), datetime.date(2022, 1, 1)],
        "b": [datetime.date(2021, 12, 1), datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)],
    }
)

>>> df.with_columns([(pl.col("a").dt.year() + pl.col("b").dt.month()).alias("diff")])
[/home/runner/work/polars/polars/polars/polars-lazy/polars-plan/src/logical_plan/optimizer/simplify_expr.rs:456] eval_binary_same_type!(left_aexpr, +, right_aexpr) = None
[/home/runner/work/polars/polars/polars/polars-lazy/polars-plan/src/logical_plan/optimizer/simplify_expr.rs:456] eval_binary_same_type!(left_aexpr, +, right_aexpr) = None
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────┬────────────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b          ┆ diff │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64  │
╞════════════╪════════════╪══════╡
│ 2022-12-01 ┆ 2021-12-01 ┆ 2034 │
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2000-01-01 ┆ 2023 │
└────────────┴────────────┴──────┘

>>> df.with_columns([(pl.col("a").dt.year().cast(pl.Int32) + pl.col("b").dt.month().cast(pl.Int32)).alias("diff")])
[/home/runner/work/polars/polars/polars/polars-lazy/polars-plan/src/logical_plan/optimizer/simplify_expr.rs:456] eval_binary_same_type!(left_aexpr, +, right_aexpr) = None
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────┬────────────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b          ┆ diff │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ date       ┆ i32  │
╞════════════╪════════════╪══════╡
│ 2022-12-01 ┆ 2021-12-01 ┆ 2034 │
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2000-01-01 ┆ 2023 │
└────────────┴────────────┴──────┘

>>> df.with_columns([(pl.col("a").dt.year() - pl.col("b").dt.month()).alias("diff")])
shape: (2, 3)
┌────────────┬────────────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b          ┆ diff │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64  │
╞════════════╪════════════╪══════╡
│ 2022-12-01 ┆ 2021-12-01 ┆ 2010 │
│ 2022-01-01 ┆ 2000-01-01 ┆ 2021 │
└────────────┴────────────┴──────┘
```

I am curious about what is the meaning of this message.

- The first expression gives me two such messages. And I suspect it should be somehow related to type differences.
- So, in the second expression, I cast them to the same type, but this time I still get one such message (less then 2 in the first time though).
- However, in the third expression, I get no message, and the only difference between the first one is minus instead of plus. So, it makes me more confusing.

It would be great if someone could help me understand this message and what is the implications of it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was just a debug statement left in the code, should be fixed in 0.16.1

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6540

Comment: Got, in my code, for adding or subtracting integers of different types (signed and unsigned), do I need to cast them to the exact same type?

Comment: if you upgrade to the latest version this should be fixed